# Using qstest to implement unit tests

Tags: package-writing, qstest

I was trying to figure out how to test my [`xpeek`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpeek) package (see https://github.com/jcsalomon/xpeek) and I came across *[What's the folk-lore on automatic testing of TeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12067/2966)* and *[Testing Framework API for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42328/2966)*.  Both of these mention the [`qstest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/qstest) package, but I’m having trouble understanding how to use it.

To be concrete, consider this test of `xspace` (`xpeek` can be used to implement `\xspace`, so this is not far removed from what I want to do):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace, qstest}
\begin{document}

\begin{qstest}{test xspace}{}
  \Expect{foo\xspace.}{foo.}
\end{qstest}

\end{document}
```

This fails, yielding this error message:

```
! Package qstest Error: Failed: test xspace
 \Expect: foo\xspace .
 <foo.
 >foo\xspace ..

See the qstest package documentation for explanation.
```

Obviously I’m missing something fundamental here, but reading the `qstest` package documentation is not making things any clearer to me.  Can anyone explain to me how to write the test so it succeeds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"`foo\xspace.`" and "`foo.`" are indeed different, thus the test must fail. `\Expect` can expand
the arguments if they are preceded by a star:

```
\Expect*{foo\xspace.}{foo.}
```

However, this will not help either, because `\xspace` is not expandable (`\futurelet` and other assignments). But we can put the argument in a box and measure the width. If `\xspace` would insert a space, the width of the
box would be larger.

```
\begin{qstest}{test xspace}{}
  \sbox0{foo\xspace.}
  \sbox2{foo.}
  \Expect*{\the\wd0}*{\the\wd2}
\end{qstest}
```

Comment: Is that what the test macros inside your packages boil down to? Seems like quite a limitation. BTW, you & Will Robertson are the only ones whose packages on CTAN use `qstest` that I can find.

Comment: @Salomon, you can take LuaTeX and look into the contents of boxes using Lua and check,
whether is a space. Testing is sometimes something like finding relevant properties of a feature that
can be checked against the expectations.

Comment: LuaTeX is a rabbit-hole I’m not looking to climb down at the moment, but it’s good to know about. I’ve added a simple test-suite based on your answer to `xpeek` at [this commit](https://github.com/jcsalomon/xpeek/commit/3e267b419e3820d149a9aaa1e84e090049f44d7d).